# Importing JavaScript Library into NativeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nativescript

I am learning NativeScript. I have a basic app working. I am now trying to import a JavaScript library that I've used in the past. I'm importing the library by using:

```
npm install git://github.com/my-company/my-project.git --save
```

I've confirmed that the package is being installed. In my view model, I then add the following:

```
var MyLibrary = require('MyLibrary');
```

That line alone causes the app to crash. Basically, NativeScript cannot seem to find it (or load it). I looked, and I can see the "MyLibrary" directory in the "node_modules" directory. The directory structure looks like this:

```
.
node_modules
  MyLibrary
    dist
      MyLibrary.min.js
    src
      MyLibrary.js
    package.json
```

The MyLibrary.js file looks like this:

```
class MyLibrary {
    process(vals) {        
        let result = 0;
        if (vals) {
            vals.forEach(function(val) {
                result = result + val;
            });
        }
        return result;
    }
}
module.exports = MyLibrary;
```

The "MyLibrary.min.js" file is the result of running it through Babel and converting it to ES5. What am I doing wrong? I'm just trying to get the following code into my view model:

```
var MyLibrary = require('MyLibrary');
var library = new MyLibrary();
var result = library.process([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Comment: I don't know if it would help, but does `require('MyLibrary/dist/MyLibrary.min.js')` work?

Comment: @jasssonpet That does work. But I want to be one of the cool kids :)

Comment: Than maybe you should check the `main` field of the `package.json`. It should be pointing to the module you want `require('MyLibrary')` to resolve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In your `package.json`, add a property like this :

```js
{
  "main": "./dist/MyLibrary.min.js"
}
```

2. In your code, use your module like this :

```js
var MyLibraryModule = require('MyLibrary');
var library = new MyLibraryModule.MyLibrary();
var result = library.process([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this for the https://github.com/rosiejs/rosie package. It seems like in the `package.json` there, it already has step 1. But requiring rosie like your method entails in step 2 still yields this error message when I do `npm test ios`: "Could not find module 'rosie'"

Comment: Ok for those who are using external packages installed via `npm`, make sure you don't do -D (save-dev), and do --save. I was able to get this to work with the js library `rosie`